# Angular 4 project showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

My Angular (v4) project works fine on my computer; however, on my friend's computer it is showing the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined 
combine

webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js

__webpack_require__

webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js

__webpack_require__ 

webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/main.ts

__webpack_require__

webpackJsonp
webpack_require__ 

webpackJsonpCallback

(anonymous function)
```

Comment: Did you make an `npm install` ?

Comment: Yes. i have done it. I have deleted the node_modules folder and made npm install.But the error exists.